# Linq sorting on sort order of inner group

Tags: c#, linq

Is this the best way to do this sort?

```
assets.OrderBy(a =>
    a.GalleryItems != null &&
    a.GalleryItems.FirstOrDefault() != null
        ? a.GalleryItems.OrderBy(gi => gi.SortOrder).First().SortOrder
        : 1000)
```

Basically I have a group of assets, which contain a group of gallery items with a sort order.  I need to get the lowest sort order from this group and sort the assets by that.  Gallery items can be null (it is coming through a service so I am unable to change this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
assets.OrderBy(a => a.GalleryItems != null && 
                    a.GalleryItems.Any()
                    ? a.GalleryItems.Min(gi => gi.SortOrder) 
                    : 1000)
```

It's actually a bit faster, since sorting the inner list takes longer than just getting the minimum value.

Comment: I like the use of min, think that's what I was after.  Looks a lot neater